# config file for cPanel database causes 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I've been trying to fix all the day. And it's definitely requiring the config that causes this to happen... Here's what I have in config.php

```
return [
    'database' => [
        'name' => 'graphgr1_depresstrology',
        'username' => 'graphgr1_mhazaa',
        'password' => '*Lesmondes2012*',
        'connection' => 'localhost',
        'options' => [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
        ]
    ]
];
```

I definitely got the name/username/password right. The user has all access privileges. And the website is also hosted in the same server (both with directnic) So any ideas what problem might be? This is driving me nuts.

Also is there something else I can put in 'options' or something to get a more detailed description about the error.

Comment: There shouldn't be a semi-colon at the end of `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`.

Comment: oooh I see. I took it out and still same problem though :(

Comment: I even tried different hosting and same thing

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting` turned on? If so, you should get useful errors reported to your browser instead of a simple cryptic 500. Do you have access to server logs? There might be something helpful in the Apache error log. There might also be an error_log present with details?